# Android:placing layouts over each other

Tags: android

i am having an issue in over-lapping layouts,i am trying to implement an login form with in the entire page , and a button at the bottom , when the user press this button a registration form slides from bottom to up  , my problems are:the first the registration form push the entire screen (i want it to overflow), the second: that i have 2 buttons with a shape background that appears on the top of registration form and the login inputs remains active 
my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_login_page"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    tools:context="com.example.a3wd.mytest10.LoginPage"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_login_page">





            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/login2Logo"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/fixawy_logoPic"
                android:src="@drawable/logo2" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/loginInputs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/login2Logo"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/loginText"
                    android:textColor="@color/loginText"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/userEmail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/myspinner"
                    android:hint="@string/nameHint"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:padding="10dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/userPassword"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/myspinner"
                    android:hint="@string/passwordHint"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/loginInputs"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_round_corner"
                android:text="@string/enterBtnTxt"

                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/passwordText"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/loginBtn"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/loginInputs"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:text="@string/forgetPassword"
                android:textColor="@color/loginText"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/facebookTxt"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/loginBtn"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/facebookTxt"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/facebookBtn"
                android:layout_width="88dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/facebookTxt"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/facebookbtn"
                android:text="@string/facebook_btn"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newUserTxt"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/newUserTxt"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/registrationBtn"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@id/registrationBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/register_btn_shape"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:onClick="registerFragment"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingEnd="40dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/registerTxt"
        android:textColor="#874f13"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/registerForm"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/newUserTxt"
            android:background="@drawable/register_back"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:paddingEnd="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/registerTxt"
    android:textColor="#874f13"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    />


    </LinearLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
```

and the java code for animation

```
 Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.anim.bottom_up);
            registrationForm.startAnimation(bottomUp);
            registrationForm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

this is the original view[image: before clicking the bottom btn]
and this is an image of the problem[image: these 2 button suppose to be in the back view]

Comment: Use bottom sheets with a custom layout  in your app available in support library 23.2 + .

Comment: is it going to work with previous versions of android

Comment: yes it will work well on older devices

Comment: thanks it works fine , but it's initial value expanded

Comment: i found the answer by using myBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);